# If Field > CharField > EmailField, does EmailField break Liskov Substitution Principle with CharField?

Tags: python, oop, theory, liskov-substitution-principle

Say I am writing a webapp with a `Form` class, and a `Form` class can have several `Fields`.

`Field` itself is an abstract class. It contains an abstract `validators` property which is a list of methods it will call to determine whether or not the content of the field is valid. These validators are invoked by a call to by the instance method `Field.run_validators(value)`

`CharField` is a `Field` subclass which allows arbitrary text. This field is always valid, as long as some string of non-zero length is given to it.

`EmailField` is a `CharField` subclass with additional requirements. This field is only valid when `value` passes a set of tests of some kind. (e.g. `'@' in value`).

My question here is: Does `EmailField` break the LSP with respect to `CharField`? Should it be a sibling class instead? Although `Field` defines variability by allowing subclasses to provide their own `validators`, `TextField` doesn't explicitly extend that variability.

I keep trying to find more explanations of the LSP, but they all reuse the same Rectangle/Square example.

Given:

```py
def transmogulate(field):
    """field must be a TextField instance."""
    assert isinstance(field, TextField)
    instance.run_validators("hello")
```

When using a `CharField`, `transmogulate(my_text_field)` will run without issue. But if `my_text_field` is an instance of `EmailField` instead, it will always raise a `ValidationError`. Is this a violation of the LSP? Or is my reasoning totally backwards? (which happens often enough)

Also you can just as happily imagine `run_validators()` returning `False` instead of raising an exception if that changes the analysis somehow; I just wanted to keep my example as close the source material as possible.

Comment: As long as it works who cares?

Answer (score 0):

I think the design is ok as long as EmailField provides the same methods as CharField ( which it seems like it does ). It follows LSP if it still quacks like a duck. Its ok for subclasses to have different implementations or behaviors.

Comment: But the same is true of the common Rectangle/Square example that breaks LSP. Square provides the same methods so it still quacks like a duck. But it behaves unexpectedly, which is I think what causes it to break the LSP.

Comment: Good point... I'm interested in hearing other answers on this. I *think* it is a little different than rectangle/square though because the problem with square as I understand it is that setHeight and setWidth now do unexpected things. However , in this case, run_validators() still just tells us if its valid or not albeit with slightly different logic. And since it is operating on user data I don't think this difference in behavior affects the programmer in the real world.